# Prove or disprove: If $P = x...y$ is a path in a $2$-connected graph $G$ then there is another $xy$-path $P'$, which is internally disjoint from $P$.

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

Prove or disprove: If $P = x...y$ is a path in a $2$-connected graph $G$ then $G$ contains another $xy$-path $P'$, which is internally disjoint from $P$.

I'm not sure where to start with this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is false. (With apologies to user [micahyoung](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/33304/micahyoung), who was intimidated into deleting a correct counterexample, while nobody noticed that the proof posted years ago was incorrect.)

The property guaranteed by a $2$-connected graph is that for any vertices $x$ and $y$, there are two internally disjoint $x-y$ paths. However, if we choose a bad $x-y$ path $P$ to start with, there is no guarantee that a second path exists.

In particular, a very roundabout path $P$ might visit *all* vertices in the graph, which definitely leaves no possibilities for $P'$ unless $x$ and $y$ happen to be adjacent. Here is an example of this happening:

[image: bad x-y path]

Answer (score -1):

You can prove this by induction on the distance of $x$ and $y$.

Base case: If $dist(x,y)=1$, then $\{x,y\}$ is an edge. Let $z$ be a vertex different from $x$ and $y$. Since the graph is 2-connected, the removal of $x$ (respectively $y$) does not disconnect the graph, therefore there is a $(x,z)-$path $P_1$ which does not contain $y$, and a $(y,z)-$path $P_2$ which does not contain $x$.
The $(x,y)-$path $P_1P_2$ is obviously internally disjoint from the trivial path $\{x,y\}$.

Inductive step: We assume that the statement holds for all pairs of vertices that have distance $\leq k$ and we take a pair of vertices $x$ and $y$ with $dist(x,y)=k+1$. Consider the shortest path from $x$ to $y$ and let $z$ be the vertex adjacent to $y$ on this path. Since $dist(x,z)=k$, from the inductive hypothesis we have that there are two internally disjoint $(x,z)-$paths, $P_1$ and $P_2$.
Furthermore, we know that the removal of $z$ does not disconnect the graph, therefore there is a $(x,y)-$path $P_3$ that does not contain $z$. From there on it is easy to construct two internally disjoint $(x,y)-$paths using $P_1$, $P_2$ and $P_3$.

Comment: This is a correct proof of a different claim: that there are two internally disjoint $x-y$ paths. It does not prove that if we pick *any* $x-y$ path $P$, then there's another one disjoint to $P$ in particular.